# Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am solving SonarQube issues , in that issues i face an bellow error but can not understant what kind of error is this ,

Here is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@DynamicUpdate
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = Vendor.TABLE_NAME)
public class Vendor 
{


    @Column(name = VENDOR_MODIFIED_BY_FOREIGN_KEY, nullable = true)

    private Integer modifiedBy;



    public Integer getModifiedBy() {

        return modifiedBy == null ? 0 : modifiedBy;

//Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed in com.bostonbyte.thelift.entities.vendors.Vendor.getModifiedBy() 




    }



    public void setModifiedBy(Integer modifiedBy) {

        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;

    }
```

I get an error at

```
 public Integer getModifiedBy() {

                return modifiedBy == null ? 0 : modifiedBy;
```

Could you please let me know what kind of error is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that, the automatic conversion of primitive data types into its equivalent Wrapper type is known as boxing and opposite operation is known as unboxing.
In your code `modifiedby` gets unboxed, for comparing with int value(0) i.e. primitive data type, after values get compared it will again boxed because its return type is Wrapper class, i think you should go with the first answer that is by @jens.

Answer (score 11):

That means, that `modifiedBy` will be unboxed, to compare it with the primitive type and than boxed, because the return value is an object.

Use:

```
return modifiedBy == null ? Integer.valueOf(0) : modifiedBy;
```

and the error should go away.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `modifiedBy` is an `Integer`, but the type of the ternary conditional expression `modifiedBy == null ? 0 : modifiedBy` is `int` (that's the type of the conditional expression when the 2nd operand is an `int` and the 3rd operand is an `Integer`, [as you can see in table 15.25-C. of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)).

Therefore `modifiedBy` is unboxed to an `int` in order to evaluate that expression.

Then it is boxed again to `Integer`, since that's the return type of the `getModifiedBy()` method.

You could change the return type of that method to `int` to avoid the boxing 
(it seems to make sense, since `getModifiedBy()` can never return `null`):

```
public int getModifiedBy() {
    return modifiedBy == null ? 0 : modifiedBy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same similar issue with Boolean.

```
return isModified == null? false : defValue
```

changed to:

```
return isModified == null? Boolean.valueOf(false) : defValue
```